# JTable getModel().setValueAt removing first element from array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jtable

I'm encountering an odd bug while updating the contents of a `JTable`. I've got a two dimensional array which is storing arrays of values to be displayed by the table (I'm only displaying one row of data at a time). When the user clicks a button, the next set of values (along with the next set of column headers) is displayed, and when the user clicks another button, it displays the previous set. The problem is that the first time I call `getModel().setValueAt`, on the first array in the two dimensional array, it is removed.
Here's the code that updates the JTable:

```
for(int i = 0; i < formattedData[displayedDataSet].length - 1; i++) {
                    TableColumn col = displayTable.getTableHeader().getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
                    col.setHeaderValue(WeatherData.WEATHER_MAP_KEYS[displayedDataSet * 5 + i]);
                    displayTable.getTableHeader().resizeAndRepaint();
                    displayTable.getModel().setValueAt(formattedData[displayedDataSet][i], 0,  i);
}

for(String s: formattedData[0]) {
                System.out.println(s);
}
```

I expect the output to be the first array in `formattedData`, but it is the second. However, commenting out the line with `displayTable.getModel().setValueAt` causes the correct result to be output. Why is this happening, and how can I update the `JTable` while preserving my array?

Comment: Probably easier just to create a new `TableModel` and set it against the existing `JTable`

Comment: That solved it for me. Thanks!